# Issue with iframe that not allow to click in back

Tags: html, css, iframe

I've this iframe that not allow me to click on back of iframe,

how can resize or allow to click on back when tha part of iframe is closed.

My code is:

```
<div class="iframe-container">
    <iframe loading="lazy" src="https://test-website.it/" allow="camera *;microphone *" ></iframe>
</div>

<style>
    .iframe-container {
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-top: 56.25%;
        position: fixed
    }

    .iframe-container iframe {
        border: 0;
        right: 0;
        position: fixed;
        width: 10rem;
        top: 25%;
        min-width: 36vw;
        min-height: 71vh;
    }

</style>
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJi02.png)